# Firebase Cloud Function sendo chamada duas vezes

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-functions

Eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/my_node/{myId}/status').onCreate(event => {
  const data = event.data.val();
  if (data == 'STATE01') {
    return event.data.ref.set('STATE02');
  }
});
```

Estou usando `onCreate`, então a função deveria ser chamada somente uma vez e não duas. Porque isto está acontecendo?

Veja os logs:

> 9:29:27.975 PM myFunction Function execution took 33 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
>
> 9:29:27.943 PM myFunction Function execution started
>
> 9:29:27.875 PM myFunction Function execution took 1059 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
>
> 9:29:26.818 PM myFunction Function execution started

Answer (score 0):

Isso porque você está fazendo mais um `set()` na sua função. E o `onCreate` é executado sempre que acontece um `set`. Para evitar a segunda execução, você pode substituir o `set` por `update`:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.database.ref('/my_node/{myId}/status').onCreate(event => {
  const data = event.data.val();
  if (data == 'STATE01') {
    return event.data.ref.parent.update({status:'STATE02'});
  }
});
```